# Does the feat Craft Arms and Armor give proficiency to weapons they make?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Does someone with the feat Craft Arms and Armor gain proficiency with weapons they make? Are they limited to making weapons they are proficient with?

Ex: Can someone with Craft Arms and Armor make exotic weapons and then wield it with out the -4 pen?

Answer (score 13):

[Gnomes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/gnome/) are the only characters who could automatically gain proficiency with weapons they have created, due to the alternate racial trait **Master Tinker**:

> **Master Tinker** Gnomes experiment with all manner of mechanical devices. Gnomes with this racial trait gain a +1 bonus on Disable Device and Knowledge (engineering) checks. They are treated as proficient with any weapon they have personally crafted. This racial trait replaces defensive training and hatred.

Comment: Ok I know I've done this before...but...How is it that if you are proficient in Craft Arms & Armor but not it its use? I can build but cant tell you if it any good to save your life.

Comment: I am a programmer, I make software. But I barely scratch the skills of my users on the software I create. I know the mechanics in and out, but not how to effectivelly use it to gain money. Those are two different skill sets.

Comment: Also, someone who makes magic weaponry does not necessarily makes the weapons. They merely enchant them with magical power. It requires the Craft skill to actually forge a sword.

Comment: I'm gonna get flagged for this as usual. But then what's the difference casting Magic Fang on sword vs making a +1 sword. Since Craft Arms & Armor seems to be doing just that, some variant of +1 to AC or hit & damage?

Comment: You mean magic weapon, because magic fang only works on natural weapons. The difference is that they are different effects. Dispel magic can remove a permanent magic weapon spell on a sword, and a non-permanent version has a duration. A magically enchanted sword would require more powerful spells (like disjunction) or to actually be destroyed to have it's enchantment removed. You can cast the spell on a non-masterwork sword, while only a masterwork sword can be permanently enchanted to be magical.